# How to adjust size of UITextView automatically ?

Tags: uitextview

I want to make speech bubbles but there is a problem adjusting size of the bubbles in UITextView.

is there a way to increase the size of the Textview automatically depending on the length of the

text by using UITextView?

Comment: did you find an answer for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay I found a better way of doing what I was suggesting. Rather then deal with the UIView and resizing depending on the text inside it. I just made the UITextView have a rounded edge which now looks like a panel. Perfect. Hope this helps someone!

If your interested in the code

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    CGRect frame = self.frame;
    frame.size.height = self.contentSize.height;
    self.frame = frame;     // Drawing code
    self.clipsToBounds = YES;
    self.layer.cornerRadius = 10.0f;    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think I understand what your getting at. I had this problem the other day. This bit of code will adjust the UITextView contents. Create a new class and call this into it via a new class. If you want to adjust the View well I'm still working on that :-P

Hope this helps

```
    - (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    CGRect frame = self.frame;
    frame.size.height = self.contentSize.height;
    self.frame = frame;     // Drawing code
}
```